# How to find out whether a keyCode corresponds to an actual character or a function key?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, keycode, nsevent

Below is my code. But how do I know whether the character is from an alphabet? (Any alphabet, not just a-z)

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSString * const character = [theEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSCharacterSet`:

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSString * const character = [theEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers];
    if ([character length] > 0)
    {
        unichar c = [character characterAtIndex:0];
        NSCharacterSet *letters = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
        if ([letters characterIsMember:c])
        {
            NSLog(@"that's a letter!");
        }
    }
}
```

If you are calling this code frequently it might pay to store `letters` as an instance variable.

Comment: Thanks! But why do you check if the character length is greater than 0? Isn't this always the case (if keyDown is triggered). Or just an example of defensive coding?

Comment: @Wesley Yes, precisely; it's purely defensive.